# Error when trying to implement amazon mturk SDK into android studio project

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to implement Amazon's mechanical turk into my android app. I have followed the instructions:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/CreatingAHIT.html#Java
but when I am specifying the third party .jar files, it gives me

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have tried taking out every combination of .jar files and found out that jaxrpc.jar is the file causing this error. Without this file, the error when running the project is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException
    at com.example.mturk.HomeworkRequest.<init>(HomeworkRequest.java:20)
    at com.example.mturk.HomeworkRequest.main(HomeworkRequest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at ...
```

where line 20 points to:

```
service = new RequesterService(new PropertiesClientConfig("../mturk.properties"));
```

and line 39 points to:

```
HomeworkRequest app = new HomeworkRequest();
```

I have tried enabling multiDex and looked around but couldn't find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now.

EDIT:
Here's my code so far. It's just a simple HIT request similar to the sample in 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/CreatingAHIT.html#Java

```
import com.amazonaws.mturk.requester.HIT;
import com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterService;
import com.amazonaws.mturk.service.exception.ServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.mturk.util.PropertiesClientConfig;

public class HomeworkRequest{

private RequesterService service;
private String title= "Math Question";
private String description = "Solve the math question shown";
private int numAssignments = 3;
private double reward = 0.05;

public HomeworkRequest(){
    service = new RequesterService(new PropertiesClientConfig("../mturk.properties"));
}

public void createHomeworkRequest(){
    try {
        HIT hit = service.createHIT(
                title, description, reward, RequesterService.getBasicFreeTextQuestion(
                        "Can you solve this math question?"), numAssignments);

        System.out.println("Created HIT: " + hit.getHITId());
        System.out.println("HIT location: ");
        System.out.println(service.getWebsiteURL() + "/mturk/preview?groupId=" + hit.getHITTypeId());
    }
    catch(ServiceException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    HomeworkRequest app = new HomeworkRequest();
    app.createHomeworkRequest();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you've developed so far?

Comment: edited original post.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at step 1 of using the MTurk Java SDK, you need to include `SDK Installation Directory]\lib\third-party` in your `classpath`.

Your inability to find third-party jars such as JaxB seems to suggest that your IDE is facing issues finding necessary jars to build.

Please let us know if you are still facing difficulties.